# How to Show TouchLocation of ImageView1 in Imageview2 ios programmatically

Tags: ios

I am Displaying Image in Imageview1 . on touch i am able to get X,Y CO-Ordinates of touch point , Now i a want to show the image area around touch points in another imageview2 ? my reference is Snap seed Application Feature Selective Adjust Zoom on click of button point on imageView1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i Think you want to show the section of first image to second image depends on Touch! you have to get touch location on first image,

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:image1];
```

Guess the image you want to show is this

```
UIImage *imageToCrop = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Abc.png"];
```

First Create Rect From point

```
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y,point.x-20,point.y-20);
UIImage *cropImage = [self crop:imageToCrop Rect:cropRect];
image2.image = cropImage;
```

(*image2 is a ImageView);

Call this Function which return cropped image from given rect

```
-(UIImage*)crop:(UIImage *)Imagecrop Rect:(CGRect)rect {

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([Imagecrop CGImage], rect);
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
return result;
}
```

All This stuff you must have to do on Touch Events!
May this Help You!

you Should also look at [This Project](https://github.com/acoomans/iOS-MagnifyingGlass)

Comment: Thanks , I am getting a memory Exception